# Errno -2 Name or service not known -- openSSL Python

Tags: python, selenium, tweepy, pyopenssl

I am using Python, Selenium, Tweepy, and openSSL to look at links gathered from tweet data. Essentially what I have my code do is check if the tweet has a link, check if it is http/https, and if it is https, it will check if the certificate has expired. Here is that chunk o fcode:

```
if rsecure.search(s1) != None:

    #driver.get(s1)
    cert=ssl.get_server_certificate((s1, 443))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    if x509.has_expired():
        print("Expired Cert")
    else:
        print( "Good Link")
    print(driver.current_url)
```

Everything is working, including checking twitter for the phrases I put in, printing the bad http links, etc., except for this portion of code. When it reaches this, it doesn't print the link, it prints: [Errno -2] Name or service not known. I've looked around and there isn't much that has helped me resolve this error. I figured it has something to do with the openSSL portion, which I don't know much about.

Any ideas? 
EDIT: it would also occasionally print this error: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)

EDIT: other code above provided portion for more context

```
import tweepy
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time

from OpenSSL import SSL
import OpenSSL
import ssl, socket
PYOPENSSL = True
#from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

#binary = FirefoxBinary('/ex50/bin/geckodriver.exe')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)


# context = ssl.create_default_context()
# conn = context.wrap_socket(
#                   socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
#                    server_hostname= hostname)

# ssl_info = conn.getpeercert()
# print(ssl_info)

securer = r'https:\S*'
badr = r'http:\S*'
rsecure = re.compile(securer)
rbad = re.compile(badr)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            if 'http' in status.text:
                if rsecure.search(status.text) != None:
                    driver.get(rsecure.search(status.text).group())
                    s1 = driver.current_url
                elif rbad.search(status.text) != None:

                    driver.get(rbad.search(status.text).group())
                    s1 = driver.current_url
```

Comment: Which line generates the error? and what's `s1` value?

Comment: The S1 value is the driver.currentURL value. I am using cloud 9 so I am not entirely sure which line it is, but I am assuming it is the lines where I generate the certificate -- I have commented out it and it works but obviously not checking for the expired certificate.

Comment: UPDATE: I found out it is this line giving the error: cert=ssl.get_server_certificate((s1, 443)) and further inspection yielded this error as well: socket.gaierror